# Why poping register changes the IP pointer

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

I was playing around with some assembly code which is

```
func:
    pop ax
    ret
main:
    push 0x44
    call func
```

i noticed that the ip pointer now points to 0x44 which the last item on the stack
i'm doing that to understand the `ROP` technique
i need to understand this behavior because when i do this

```
func:
    ret
main:
   call func
```

it works as expected with EIP pointer points back to the original code
so what is the difference `pop` made to change the code flow ?
and does the `pop ax` assigns last value on the the stack to `ax` ?

Comment: Because `call` and `ret` also use the stack.

Comment: why don't you read in manual, what `call` and `ret` does?

Comment: Consult the instruction set reference to see what each instruction does. TL;DR: `call` places the return address on the stack, `ret` removes it. If you insert a `pop` before it, then of course that return address will get removed and `ret` will use the next item which is likely wrong.

Comment: if someone will down vote at least explain to me why.. please :)

Comment: @Ped7g i already tried but i didn't understand it properly .. i'm still newbie

Comment: Next time if you actually try to read the manual, then say so and quote the relevant part that you had trouble understanding so we can explain it. Anyway, you might want to learn a little more about the basic things before you move on to advanced topics such as reverse engineering and ROP. Also, learn to use a debugger to single step the code and see what it is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EIP is a register.  A value on the stack isn't EIP (yet), it's a return address or a value that might become EIP if you pop it into EIP by executing `ret`.

Think of `ret` as how x86 spells `pop eip`.

---

Executing `push 0x44` increases the EIP register by 2, the length of the instruction.

If you use the `0x44` as a return address by executing `ret` while `ESP` is pointing to it, then EIP becomes `0x44`.

And note that IP is the low 16 bits of EIP.  Unless you really mean the low 16 bits, write EIP instead of IP.

Answer (score 1):

To understand this code, a look on the real program flow may help (inverting the order of the code and assuming a linear flow):

```
main:           ; entry point IP = main
    push 0x44   ; 0x44 on top of stack
    call func   ; PUSH 'next cur IP'(=func) on the stack
func:
    pop ax      ; POP 'next cur IP' from the stack(=this)
    ret         ; return to current stack value (=0x44 = IP) which is probably invalid
```

This is quite similar to the following technique acquiring the current IP:

Because there are no instructions to get the current value of the *Instruction Pointer (IP)*, the following code is a handy workaround to get its value:

```
    call next   ; call next address
next:
    pop ax      ; POP the current value of the IP (AX=this address)
```